# cannot get checkboxes value using drupal form api

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

i have form in drupal which uploads images and has got few checkboxes in it.
Here is the form:

```
$form['checklist_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Check List'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,  
  );
$form['checklist_fieldset']['heating'] = array(
   '#type' => 'checkboxes',
   '#title' => t('Heating options'),

   '#options' => array(
  '0' => t('Yes'),
  '1' => t('No')
  ),
   '#description' => t('Heating details.')
  );
```

and here is my submit function where i am processing image upload and grabbing the checkboxes value as well. I am getting the success message and image is getting uploaded but not getting the value of check boxes.

```
function property_add_view_submit($form,&$form_state){
$validators = array();



if($file = file_save_upload('p_file1',$validators,file_direcotry_path)){
$heating = array_keys($form_state['values']['heating']);
drupal_set_message(t('Property Saved! '.$heating));
dpm( $form_state['values']['heating']);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `#options` on a FAPI element the value passed to the `$form_state` *is* the array key, so you don't need to use `array_keys()`.

I'm not sure why you're using `checkboxes` for a yes/no, usually one would use a simple `checkbox` element. However if that's really what you want to do:

1. Your `#options` can't contain on option with `0` as the array key, it will be automatically filtered out and you'll never know if that option has been checked.
2. You should use `$heating_options_chosen = array_filter($form_state['values']['heating']` to get the selected checkbox options.

I honestly think your code should look like this though:

```
$form['checklist_fieldset']['heating'] = array(
 '#type' => 'checkbox',
 '#title' => t('Heating options'),
 '#options' => array(
   '1' => t('Yes'),
   '0' => t('No')
  ),
  '#description' => t('Heating details.')
); 



$heating_checked = $form_state['values']['heating'] == 1;
```

Comment: well..iam using checkboxes because i wanted to use it as a check box group.

Comment: ah ok that makes more sense, glad the answer helped either way

Comment: How to toggle a text field depending on the value/options  of checkbox? @Clive

Comment: @PreritMohan For Drupal 6 you'll need to do it manually I think, but for Drupal 7 you can use [`#states`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states).

Comment: @PreritMohan If you need to ask a new question use the link at the top of the page, putting it in comments isn't useful to anyone

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/toggle-text-field-depending-on-checkbox-value-in-drupal-6

Can you help now? @Clive

Comment: useful array_filter() to omit non checked box, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I have checkbox Friends and options are like

```
[ ] abc  
[ ] def  
[ ] ghi  
[ ] jkl
```

And I want to know which options user have marked, then use below function.

```
if ($form_state->getValue('friends') != NULL) {

  foreach ($form_state->getValue('friends') as $key => $value) {

    if ($value != 0) {
      $friends = $friends . ", " . $key;
      $friends = substr_replace($friends, "", 0, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

If user has chosen `abc` and `ghi` then you will get `1`,`3` as result in `$friends`

If you wanted to know the value then use `$friends = $friends.", ".$value;`

it worked for me..hope it will help you as well :)